# Exchange DAG File Share Witness needs reconnecting after restart

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2016

I have a pair of Windows Sever 2012 R2 DataCenter servers running Exchange 2016 Std  forming between them my Database Availability Group DAG01.

As there are only two Exchange servers involved in this setup, I also have a standalone Windows Server 2012 R2 DataCenter server as a file share witness.

Whenever I restart the FSW server the DAG goes into failed state until I run Set-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup to reconfigure the WitnessServer.

Is this normal behaviour that I should be expecting or is the FSW meant to come back up as an active part of the DAG when it's restarted?

Comment: Did you wait some min here after you rebooted your FSW? In our Exchange 2016 Enterprise Deployment the FSW perform auto reboots every time when it automatically got windows updates. The state is always ok here once the patch process finished. So I think you need to wait 15min or something like that.

Comment: The purpose of the FSW is to maintain quorum in the event that a DAG member fails. If the FSW is unavailable the DAG should still have quorum as long as both DAG members are available. I think this points to a problem with the DAG itself, not the FSW.

Comment: There is still quorum and the DAG remains operational, but it claims to be in a failure state as the FSW seems to become disconnected from it.